# Invalid bundle structure. The binary file '***' is not permitted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, share-extension

This is my first time when I integrate, share extension to my app. I don't know after adding a share extension to my app I get this error while uploading my app build on Test Flight. App work fine on a device not getting any error, but when I try to upload my app a get this error.

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: it is clear that you should need to fix your bundles according to Apple standards

Comment: I am new to swift so please guide me.
what is the standards and how to fix bundle ?
please elaborate the answer

Comment: Also please check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing file FAIcon from my copy bundle resource work for me.

Comment: I think FAIcon pod and its bundle string identifier is something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your bundle `CFBundleVersion`

According to Apple document as below

> Each integer provides information about the build version in the format [Major].[Minor].[Patch]:
> Major: A major revision number.
> Minor: A minor revision number.
> Patch: A maintenance release number.
> You can include more integers but the system ignores them.
> You can also abbreviate the build version by using only one or two integers, where missing integers in the format are interpreted as zeros. For example, 0 specifies 0.0.0, 10 specifies 10.0.0, and 10.5 specifies 10.5.0.

As well as your app bundle version you should be aware of your pods has correct short bundle versions are correct. You can check them from info.plist